# Is it possible for image to have multiple tags?

Tags: docker, dockerhub

When I am pushing new image to repo I would like it to have two tags for example `0.2` and `latest`. This would allow to always pull latest image version by using `latest` tag and a specific version by using `0.2` tag for example. Is it possible with docker?

Is there any workaround? The only solution I see is to make two separate pushes...

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can create multiple tags:

```
docker tag <id> <user>/<image>:0.2
docker tag <id> <user>/<image>:latest
```

and push these.

Comment: From Docker 1.10 onwards you can also do: `docker build -t <user>/<image>:0.2 -t <user>/<image>:latest .`

Comment: Do you need to push for each tag in order for each tag to be pushed, or can you push with just one tag?

Comment: @ZoidbergWill if I build like this with say, 3 tags, how many 'docker push' instructions do I need to run to get the image into my private Artifactory registry with all of those tags?

Comment: @Wmbuch @EdRandall as of `Docker version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a` I had to push *each* tag independently, even though they locally point to the same image id. The pushes after the first one are "layer exists" for each layer obviously so they don't transmit any data per se, but have to be executed anyway.

Comment: Did you try `docker push user/repository` without a tag? I think that pushes for every tag.

Comment: @Adirio this behavior has been changed and pushing without a tag no longer pushes *all* tags, see https://github.com/docker/cli/pull/2220

Comment: @jtschoonhoven so I need to push both tags separately right?

Answer (score 261):

You can build an image with several tags and then push the image with the `--all-tags` option.

Example:

```
docker build -t reg/user/image:foo -t reg/user/image:latest .

docker push reg/user/image --all-tags
```

Older Docker clients that do not support `--all-tags` will push all tags by default (simply omit the option), newer clients will only push `latest` by default. As an alternative, you may want to push each tag separately.

Comment: looks like pushing the local image name assumes dockerhub - I'm using Docker desktop
so i'd have to push each tag individually. is there away to set a destination registry/repo?

Comment: @badcop666 The "reg" in `reg/user/image` is meant to identify the target registry. (Docker Hub's registry is `docker.io` and the default namespace is called `library`. Hence, if you pull or push an image that is called "foo" it implicitly identifies it as `docker.io/library/foo`.) – Use `registry.your-domain.com/your-namespace/your-image`, that should work. This assumes the CLI.

Comment: Should be the accepted answer. The current accepted doesn't explain how to do the push. Is it one push? two?

Comment: Note that in Docker 20.03 this code will push only `reg/user/image:latest`, **not all tags**. The current behaviour, when all tags are pushed when tag is omitted in `docker push` is undocumented and considered confusing, so it was [fixed](https://github.com/docker/cli/pull/2220) now though you still can push all tags in 20.03 by adding `-a/--all-tags` flag

Comment: This is not a very good solution at all. If you have been building locally for a long time you might have 300 tags locally, but maybe the latest one you built only has 2 tags (`latest` and version number). If you use `--all-tags`, it tries to push literally all of your tags up. What is actually needed is a solution for pushing only the 2 tags that you just built, not your entire history of 300 tags.

Answer (score 36):

You need to do one push per each version like:

```
docker tag test:latest <repo>/<user>/test:latest
docker push <repo>/<user>/test:latest

docker tag test:0.2 <repo>/<user>/test:0.2
docker push <repo>/<user>/test:0.2
```

You can also combine and say the `latest` version is `0.2` like:

```
docker tag <repo>/<user>/test:latest <repo>/<user>/test:0.2
docker push <repo>/<user>/test:0.2
```

So those will point the same image layer.

Comment: NO, if do not pushed latest tag. you cannot find in registy. did you tried?

Answer (score 23):

**UPDATE: Prior to Jan 2021**

It pushes all the tags, if you dont specify the tags in push command.

```
docker tag user/imagename:tag1
docker tag user/imagename:tag2

docker push user/imagename
```

Comment: WARNING: it appears this is no longer the case as of Jan 2021
https://github.com/docker/cli/pull/2220

Answer (score 1):

There are valid reasons for having multiple tags on an image (see OP) but if you are wanting to add tags for informational purposes, you may be better off with **image labels**.

Docker labels are *inside* the image rather than applied to it in the registry. This means the labels are immutable and always get copied with the image.

[Label Schema](http://label-schema.org/rc1/) defines a list of interoperable labels for things like `version`, `vcs-ref`, `build-date` and others.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to refer the image by hash, but "copy a tag" you can do the following:

```
docker tag image:origin_tag image:target_tag
docker push image:target_tag
```