# Pushing multiple Docker tags to Artifactory using Bitbucket pipe

Tags: artifactory, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a Pipeline in Bitbucket that builds a Docker image.  It then uses the artifactory-docker pipe to push that image to Artifactory.  Here is the relevant part of my pipeline.

```
- docker build
    --pull
    --tag "${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/artifact_name:${BITBUCKET_COMMIT}"
    --tag "${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/artifact_name:latest"
    --target "artifact_name"
    --file "path/to/Dockerfile" .
- pipe: JfrogDev/artifactory-docker:0.2.12
  variables:
    ARTIFACTORY_URL: $ARTIFACTORY_URL
    ARTIFACTORY_USER: $ARTIFACTORY_USER
    ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD: $ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD
    DOCKER_TARGET_REPO: $DOCKER_TARGET_REPO
    DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG: '${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/artifact_name:${BITBUCKET_COMMIT}'
    FOLDER: 'artifact_name'
    BUILD_NAME: 'artifact_name'
```

This works as expected, creating the image in Artifactory with the correct `${BITBUCKET_COMMIT}` value as the tag.

I *also* need to push `${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/artifact_name:latest` to Artifactory.  Is there a way to do this with the single pipe?  How can I push both the `${BITBUCKET_COMMIT}` and `latest` tags to Artifactory?

I've tried adding another `DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG` element to the configuration, but it simply used the second one.  And I've looked in the documentation but haven't found any information about how to push more than one tag at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You have to tag the image with the `latest` tag before using the pipe to push.

```
script:
  - docker build -t soldev-art-docker.jfrog.team/docker-pipe-example:$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER .
  # tag the image as latest and docker will push both tags for ya
  - docker tag soldev-art-docker.jfrog.team/docker-pipe-example:$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER soldev-art-docker.jfrog.team/docker-pipe-example:latest
  # now both tags will be pushed to the registry
  - pipe: JfrogDev/artifactory-docker:0.2.12
    variables:
      ARTIFACTORY_URL: '<string>'
      ARTIFACTORY_USER: '${ARTIFACTORY_USER}'
      ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD: '${ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD}'
      DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG: 'soldev-art-docker.jfrog.team/docker-pipe-example:${BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER}'
      DOCKER_TARGET_REPO: 'docker-stage-local'
```

This post also explains how to deal with multiple tags https://stackoverflow.com/a/31963727/2183102

Comment: This did not work for me.  I've tried tagging twice in the build command (see updated example), as well as tagging as a separate step, per your example.  The artifactory-docker pipe only pushes the tag specified by the DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG parameter.